# LLC Officer and Meeting Requirements

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

If an individual forms a LLC, and that individual has no staff or employees, is he required to appoint himself as an officer, hold meetings, or conduct similar activities?

Jurisdiction: U.S.

Comment: This is a question of state law that differs from one state to another. There is not a uniform rule at either the federal or state level in the United States. Even within a given state, there are frequently different options that can be elected that have different requirements (e.g. manager managed v. member managed LLCs) and further variation is allowed via an operating agreement.